# Are both "didn't" and "haven't" correct in "I'm not sure．I ___（not check）it carefully."?

Tags: grammaticality, exam-questions, past-vs-present-perfect

> Are there any mistakes in your homework，Jim？
> I'm not sure．I ______（not check）it carefully．

The answer to this question is 'didn't check', can I say 'haven't checked'?
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. *didn't check* indicates that the action was not done in the past, while *haven't checked* indicates that the action was not done in the past and has continued to not be done. In the context, both are fine.